# addicted to drink coffee

Tags: idiomatic-language

Are the following sentences idiomatic and mean the same thing?

> I am addicted to drink coffee
>
> I am addicted to drinking coffee
>
> I am addicted to coffee drinking

Comment: The first is not idiomatic, as we speak of being addicted to _something_ (the habit of drinking coffee) rather than a verb (drink). You could also say simply "I am addicted to coffee".